# I am unable to connect to internet

Tags: internet

I use Ubuntu 12.04 as dual boot with windows 7(ultimate). I use D-link DIR-600M and an external usb-lan adapter(Enter- E100-U) as my integrated motherboard lan is not working. Using static ip configuration(given by ISP) I am able to use internet in windows 7(Using DHCP) & but in Ubuntu it's show network disconnected under Wired network and sometimes it connect for some second and then it disconnect.

network configuration
IP address 10.12.29.xx
Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0
Default Route 10.12.29.xx
DNS 172.16.0.1,8.8.8.8

Comment: you could just need a firmware upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Can your Ubuntu drivers and files utilize the type of internet you use? I used to use 12.04 and it couldn't connect to certain types of internet such as networks labeled 5G. You may need to get a more recent version of Ubuntu to connect. I would recommend 15 or 16.04.

Comment: I face same problem while running Ubuntu 16.00 from live-usb.

Comment: What are your specs? It could just be a problem with not having specs that meet the Ubuntu requirements.
Here is what you need to run Ubuntu 12.04
700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
512 MiB RAM (system memory)
5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media

Comment: MY computer specs are:       Motherboard- Intel Corporation D945GCNL;
CPU-Genuine Intel(R) CPU 2160 @ 1.80GHz;  Memory-2GB;
display-Samsung SyncMaster 720N; Hard disk-Western Digital(500GB)(100 GB is alloted to Ubuntu);
id:  network:0
description: Ethernet interface;       physical id: 1
logical name: eth1 ;serial: 00:e0:00:10:c6:39 ;   size: 100Mbit/s capacity: 100Mbit/s 
configuration:
autonegotiation=off;     broadcast=yes ; driver=dm9601
driverversion=22-Aug-2005 ;duplex=half
firmware=Davicom DM96xx USB 10/100 Ether ;   link=no ; multicast=yes
port=MII ;     speed=100Mbit/s

Comment: Everything checks out, and at this point I really don't now how to help you. Sorry.